# GWT MouseOverHandler and MouseOutHandler horrible result, element keeps fire mouse over and mouse out events at the same time?

Tags: gwt, vaadin, mouseover, mouseout

I have a problem with the GWT MouseHandler events:

This the code:

```
@Override
    protected void extend(ServerConnector target) {
        final Widget widget = ((ComponentConnector) target).getWidget();

        widget.addDomHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent e) {
                widget.setVisible(false);
            }
        }, MouseOverEvent.getType());

        widget.addDomHandler(new MouseOutHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
                widget.setVisible(true);
            }
        }, MouseOutEvent.getType());
    }
```

I am using Vaadin, this is inside the an extension connector. The hovered element is a simple label. Everything works great when I either use only the MouseOverHandler or the MouseOutHandler, but when I use them together I get this horrible result (please, take a look at the video to understand what I mean):

http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=jrxpq0%3E&s=8#.VMSkFnCUc4Q

Why does MouseOverHandler and MouseOutHandler do so when they are together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with gwt. You are hiding the widget, when the mouse is over it. When the element hides, the mouse is not over it anymore and so the mouseOut event is triggered, which makes the widget visible again. This will trigger the mouseOver event again and the loop begins again.

It is basically this:

```
<div onMouseOver="this.style='visibility:hidden;'" onMouseOut="this.style=''">blub</div>
```

Or on jsfiddle to play around: http://jsfiddle.net/9cwsqca4/

Comment: Yes, I understood what you mean. But I have tried even to use the `widget.addStyleName()` to add a CSS class with `visibility: hidden` on over and removes it on mouse out, and the beauty is that I still experience this  "loop", why?

Comment: when you set the visibility to hidden, the element hides and the mouse that was over the element before is not over the element anymore. This means the mouse went out of the element and so the onMouseOut event has to be triggered. it does not matter if you set `visibility:hidden` directly or by a CSS class. What are you trying to do? If you want to hide something while the mouse is over it you should attach the events to a surrounding div. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/1bu2e00r/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1bu2e00r/3/ works in other browsers than firefox too (at least chrome, haven't testet IE)

Comment: The last fiddle you posted is what I was trying to do! Thanks! Anyway, so it happens that in this case `visibility: hidden` has the same meaning of `display: none`, I thought that when you set `visibility` to hidden the element just hides but it continues to occupy the space it needs in the page (unlike with `display: none`, where the element doesn't occupy its space anymore), so if it continues to occupy the space it needs, the mouse continues to be over it, but it isn't so in this case, right?

Comment: I was not sure about that, too. But i testet it (firefox and chromium on linux), and mouse events do not fire on hidden elements.